# How to fix strange font rendering (some taller characters) in Google Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I want to use the Aller font on my website, which seems to work fine in Firefox. In Chrome however, the 's' and 'k' characters (and only those) have a bigger height than the other characters.

The font renders correctly in Firefox (on Linux and MacOS), in Chrome (on MacOS), but not in Chrome on Linux. Font is not installed locally on the Linux machine.

Css rule:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Aller";
  src: url("../fonts/aller/Aller_Lt.ttf");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Chrome (on Linux) preview of the font (seems to be good):
[image]

Screenshot of text on my website with incorrect font rendering (taller 's') with Chrome:

[image]

Screenshot of same website on same machine with Firefox with correct font rendering:

[image]

How can I make sure that in Chrome the font is rendered correctly? Is this an issue with Chrome, my code or the font itself?

Comment: Might be issue with the font size, when you try to give it in decimal, try avoiding odd nos. too because some fonts act wired on odd font size try 12,14,16 etc.
rest I hope you already added the font-smoothening css.

Comment: @AwsmeSandy you are right, in some font sizes the problem doesn't occur. It seems that it's not related to odd or even sizes. With font-size 11, 13, 16, 18px there is no problem, with 12, 14, 15, 17 the 's' has a different size. I've tried font-smoothening but that doesn't seem to affect the result. Is there any way the font can be used in all font sizes without problems?

Comment: Some fonts work like this way, I mean buggy. so you need to make 1px up or down, or try the actuall font-weight of the font. I mean if its 400, then only use 400 not 500 or 300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually a problem with fonts that aren't hinted, or not hinted correctly. There are PS Private settings you can configure in the font (called BlueValues, or OtherBlues - [more information on these here](https://www-cdf.fnal.gov/offline/PostScript/T1_SPEC.PDF)) that help keep all of the characters on the same line like this - if they aren't present, the rendering just chooses the closest pixel without regard for if it's above the others. The problem will be less noticeable in the larger font sizes, and will vary from browser to browser like you've witnessed.

It doesn't look like this font is hinted - [looking at the specimen page](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Aller), you can see a similar issue with the `a` and `p` of `alphabet`. I'd advise trying to use a hinted font, or adding the hints yourself, if you're interested in that (and the license allows it).